# WEB.API does not deserialize incoming JSON in POST method

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created Web.Api based on .Net-Core. There are two methods:

1. **IEnumerable GetRoles()** - (Get)
2. **ResponseObject GetUsers(PagerRequest pagerRequest**) - (Post). It has the following attributes: [Route("api/users/getusers")]
       [HttpPost]

Both methods are called by Angular. Method GetRoles is working find but problem is in POST.

PagerRequest is a simple class which has a few int properties. It's filled in by Angular. Fiddler shows correct JSON:

```
POST http://localhost/Pir.API/api/users/getusers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 84
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

{
  "CountButtons": 5,
  "ItemsCount": 0,
  "PageSize": 5,
  "CurrentPageIndex": 0
}
```

GetUsers method is calling but input parameter is not initialized. In another words desirialization is not working and I cannot understand why.

Before this project was based on classic .Net and run in the IIS.  It was working fine. But .Net CORE is a problems.

Who knows where the problem is?

Below code examples:

-------------- PagerRequest.cs --------------------

```
public class PagerRequest
{
     public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
     public int PageSize { get; set; }
     public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
     public int CountButtons { get; set; }
 }
```

-------------- PagerRequest.ts --------------------

```
export class PagerRequest{
    ItemsCount:number;
    PageSize:number;
    CurrentPageIndex:number;
    CountButtons:number;    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the framework to read the data from the request body.
Do this with the `FromBody Attribute`

```
[HttpPost]
ResponseObject GetUsers([FromBody]PagerRequest pagerRequest)
```

*Note: If performing a HttpPost, the name GetUsers is missleading. A tip is to change that*

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Why was it working in classing application without this attribute?

Comment: @MikeTkachev Np, please accept answer :), In Asp.Net Web Api/MVC reading request data from the body was default in Controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are missing the `FromBody`.

2) One tip while working on apis is to configure [Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle) .  Swagger creates a sample html by default where you can see what type of request body is needed from the UI frameworks (for example see this url https://petstore.swagger.io, all the api endpoints are visible as html by default and we can see the type of request needed).

Hope this helps.